# How do you implement a slide transition between indexed stacks?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a smooth transition from on stack to another with a slide transition. I have the index set up as a counter and each time i press the button it increments and moves on to the next stack. is there a way to create a slide transition between each stack in an indexed stack.

```
int _counter = 0;

void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

  _counter++;
    }
);
}



   child: IndexedStack(
              index: _counter,
              children: <Widget>[

            Container(

                color: Colors.grey,
                alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
                child: Container(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Stack 1",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Container(

                color: Colors.grey,
                alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
                child: Container(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Stack 2",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Container(

                color: Colors.grey,
                alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
                child: Container(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Stack 3",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Container(

                color: Colors.grey,
                alignment: Alignment.center, // where to position the child
                child: Container(
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "Stack 4",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter(),
    tooltip: 'Next page',
    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
  ),
);
```

Here is the edited post with the code that i currently have.

Comment: Can you show us what you got so far?

Comment: After 3 years still looking for solution

Comment: After 4 years still looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

try using `PageController` instead of a `IndexedStack`
check out [the docs for PageController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController-class.html)